# Apple watch having any controls which is scrolling horizontally except table?

Tags: ios, apple-watch

Apple watch having any controls which is scrolling horizontally except table.
Anyone have any idea related to this.

Comment: Have you actually tried anything or done any research into this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no horizontal scrolling control.  You can create multiple Interface Controllers and arrange them as pages, in which case the user will be able to swipe left or right to flip between them, but they're pages and not continuous scrolling.